# Ресурсы для изучения YII

Tags: php, yii

Я изучил базовые навыки работы с фреймворком (models relations forms and). Чем теперь заняться, чтобы продвигаться дальше, есть ли какие нибудь ссылки видекурсы или что-то для изучения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На мой взгляд эффективнее учить в процессе работы. Я, например, стал находить на фрилансе задачи, типа разработать простой сайт и после беглого прочтения документации сразу брался за такие задачи, а в ходе работы гуглю и уже более глубоко познаю фреймворк.

Answer (score 0):

Когда изучал yii фреймверк, купил книгу, много читал. На форуме читал документацию. Запоминалось тяжело, понималось плохо.  Это, вероятно и была моя ошибка, что я изучал фрейм, но не практиковался. Когда поставил себе первую цель написать сайт который мне было нужено сделать, сразу же появились вопросы, которые я решал по мере их поступления. Информация усваивалась линейно, и я знал уже как решать те или иные проблемы.

Собственно этого и вам советую. Не засиживайтесь на обучении долго, только базовое можно посмотреть, все остальное изучайте на практике.

Если нет идеи для сайта, то вспомните, возможно вас уже просили знакомые сделать сайт кошечек или сайт визитку для какого то предприятия.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы ещё добавил, что не стоит сразу творить идеальный продукт.
Надо сделать хоть что-то, но по возможности максимально быстро.
А потом уже, получив работающий продукт, думать как его улучшить, привести к стандартам MVC и прочее.
Времена когда было принято вначале в совершенстве изучить, потом долго планировать и долго-долго создавать идеальный продукт безвозвратно ушли.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала надо знать и понимать сам язык PHP, верстку.
Обязательна база знаний - без нее браться за фреймворк неправильно.
В первую очередь ресурсы:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-README.html
http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/
Взять задачу небольшую - например написать сайт визитку себе, портфолио - и шаг за шагом постепенно осваивать. Не знаком фреймворк - Уставновил - О, запустилось - А как вывести переменные - А теперь подключить отображение - Ммм, MVC, почитаю что это - пора бы из базы данные драть и тд.
Самый лучший способ - практика, не просмотр каких то видео и "тупое повторение". Успехов.

Answer (score 0):

http://stuff.cebe.cc/yii2-guide.ru.pdf

А вообще, как сказали выше - начинай работать. Тогда вы получите ПРАКТИЧЕСКИЙ опыт. С каждой новой задачей вам придется "копать" - это и есть лучшее изучение нюансов языка\технологии